# Mysql: Programmatically remove all foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm working with a bit of a dodgey database at the moment, there are foreign keys defined in all the wrong places all over the place, I'd like to remove them all and then start from scratch. I don't wish to remove the column, just the foreign key relationships.

How can I remove all foreign keys from an entire database? (Or table by table).

Thanks.

Edit: Forgot to say, I have PHPMyAdmin available to use.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a PHP script to loop through the information_schema.key_column_usage table and drop each foreign key:

```
<?php
    $DBNAME = 'your db name';
    $USER = 'username';
    $PASSWORD = 'your password';
    $SERVER = 'localhost';  //Or Write your IP Address

    $conexion = new mysqli($SERVER,$USER,$PASSWORD,$DBNAME);
    $SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT table_name, constraint_name"
    ." FROM information_schema.key_column_usage"
    ." WHERE constraint_schema = '$DBNAME'"
    ." AND referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL";

    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $SQL);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        mysqli_query($conexion, "ALTER TABLE `$row[table_name]`"
        ."DROP FOREIGN KEY `$row[constraint_name]`")
        or die(mysqli_error());
    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: Does this approach always work? or could you potentially run into FOREIGN KEYs that are dependent on others? Just tried this approach in Groovy against a MySQL database and ran into some error telling my syntax was wrong. very strange.

Comment: @tyndall: If the error said that your syntax is wrong, then it means the database hasn't even tried to perform any operation yet. Your best bet is to fix the syntax error first.

Comment: Still not sure what the problem was... I was able to take one line at a time and run it on the database. But the full list with semicolons as line endings would not run. And I was not able to run them in the order that comes out of the information_schema.key_column_usage query. Will do some more research to see if there are dependent foreign keys this weekend. I'll recreate the database and try again.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a tool to access MySQL Metadata programatically. JDBC, ODBC, MySQL's native API or ADO.NET. From the Metadata extract all existing foreign keys. Loop through all of them and execute:

```
alter table INSERT_TABLE_NAME_HERE drop constraint INSERT_CONSTRAINT_NAME_HERE;
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered another similar question ([Is it possible to drop all foreign key constraints on a table at once in mySQL 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323462/is-it-possible-to-drop-all-foreign-key-constraints-on-a-table-at-once-in-mysql-5/16717776#16717776)), but thought it might be worthwhile to include the answer here.

This solution is purely in mysql by creating a procedure to loop through the table constraints and drop them one at a time.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dropForeignKeysFromTable;

delimiter ///
create procedure dropForeignKeysFromTable(IN param_table_schema varchar(255), IN param_table_name varchar(255))
begin
    declare done int default FALSE;
    declare dropCommand varchar(255);
    declare dropCur cursor for 
        select concat('alter table ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' DROP FOREIGN KEY ',constraint_name, ';') 
        from information_schema.table_constraints
        where constraint_type='FOREIGN KEY' 
            and table_name = param_table_name
            and table_schema = param_table_schema;

    declare continue handler for not found set done = true;

    open dropCur;

    read_loop: loop
        fetch dropCur into dropCommand;
        if done then
            leave read_loop;
        end if;

        set @sdropCommand = dropCommand;

        prepare dropClientUpdateKeyStmt from @sdropCommand;

        execute dropClientUpdateKeyStmt;

        deallocate prepare dropClientUpdateKeyStmt;
    end loop;

    close dropCur;
end///

delimiter ;
```

To use the procedure on one of your tables just use the following, replacing table_schema and table_name with your values:

```
call dropForeignKeysFromTable('table_schema', 'table_name');
```