# Drop all table constraints in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, constraints

My question is how do we delete or remove all the constraints defined on a table in MySQL database at one go. Is there any possible way to do it with a single LOC or do we have to write instruction to remove each type of constraint individually. Could anyone help me out. A small script too would as it becomes too tedious to remember all the constraint names for a table and then remove them. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this post has the solution you need?


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323462/is-it-possible-to-drop-all-foreign-key-constraints-on-a-table-at-once-in-mysql-5

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're still looking for an answer after 3 years. Probably not, but here's a procedure to remove all table constraints (primary, foreign key, unique, check). It also removes auto_increment and NOT NULL from columns.

This code is provided as-is and should be considered highly dangerous as it will modify a lot of columns and tables:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dropAllConstraintsForAllTablesInSchema;

DELIMITER ///
CREATE PROCEDURE dropAllConstraintsForAllTablesInSchema(IN param_table_schema VARCHAR(255))
  BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE dropCommand VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE dropCur CURSOR FOR
      SELECT
          concat('alter table ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ' MODIFY ', column_name, ' ', column_type, ' ', replace(extra, 'auto_increment', ''), ';')
      FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
        WHERE table_schema = param_table_schema
          AND (IS_NULLABLE = FALSE OR EXTRA REGEXP 'auto_increment')
      UNION
      SELECT CASE constraint_type
             WHEN 'FOREIGN KEY'
               THEN concat('alter table ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ' DROP FOREIGN KEY ', constraint_name, ';')
             WHEN 'UNIQUE'
               THEN concat('alter table ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ' DROP INDEX ', constraint_name, ';')
             WHEN 'PRIMARY KEY'
               THEN concat('alter table ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ' DROP PRIMARY KEY;')
             WHEN 'CHECK'
               THEN concat('alter table ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ' DROP CHECK ', constraint_name, ';')
             END
      FROM information_schema.table_constraints
      WHERE constraint_type IN ('FOREIGN KEY', 'UNIQUE', 'PRIMARY KEY', 'CHECK')
            AND table_schema = param_table_schema;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN dropCur;

    read_loop: LOOP
      FETCH dropCur
      INTO dropCommand;
      IF done
      THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
      END IF;

      SET @sdropCommand = dropCommand;

      PREPARE dropClientUpdateKeyStmt FROM @sdropCommand;

      EXECUTE dropClientUpdateKeyStmt;

      DEALLOCATE PREPARE dropClientUpdateKeyStmt;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE dropCur;
  END///

DELIMITER ;
```

To use this procedure, simply run:

```
call dropAllConstraintsForAllTablesInSchema('table_schema');
```

Again, use at your own caution. It may have some untested side effects on your column definitions.