# Converting to MyISAM, `foreign_key_checks = 0` Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb, myisam

I'm working on some scripts to programmatically automate a database migration, and at the end of a long series of compromises working in a system I didn't design, own, or maintain, I need to convert a number of MySQL InnoDB tables to MyISAM tables.  However, when I attempt to alter a table

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE catalog_category_entity ENGINE=MyISAM;
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
mysql>
```

MySQL complains.  This is expected.  However, if I disable the `foreign_key_checks`, I get the same results

```
mysql> SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
mysql> ALTER TABLE catalog_category_entity ENGINE=MyISAM;
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

This happens regardless of my setting the key check at the global or session level.   I assume the problem here is the table in questions has **other** InnoDB table which reference it, and MySQL refuses to end up in a state where an InnoDB table references a table that's not InnoDB. (I may be incorrect on this, and I'm more than happy to be corrected)

Is there a quick way to handle this situation?  I basically want all tables in the database to be MyISAM, and tracing out all the relationships myself and/or manually removing the contraints seems very time consuming, and  the sort of thing that a computer would be better at.

If the answer is "suck it up and do the work" I'm happy to hear that from an expert — I just don't want to waste the time if I don't need to.

If it matters the language I'm programming in in `PHP`, but I'm happy for solutions that require other languages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql: Programmatically remove all foreign keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252868/mysql-programmatically-remove-all-foreign-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys. Delete the keys before changing the engine:

```
> ALTER TABLE catalog_category_entity DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_name;
> ALTER TABLE catalog_category_entity ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

You can find the foreign key name by calling:

```
> SHOW CREATE TABLE catalog_category_entity;
```

This may be helpful: [Delete all foreign keys in database(MySql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546477/delete-all-foreign-keys-in-databasemysql)

Comment: +1 for good information — but there's a large number of tables involved here — I was hoping for a command that does all that for me.

Comment: @AlanStorm Ahh not sure, whether such command exists. Why do you want to convert to MyISAM? You will lose some protection from anomalies, that is guaranteed by the foreign keys.

Comment: Agreed, but see "end of a long series of compromises working in a system I didn't design, own, or maintain"

Comment: @AlanStorm Here it was discussed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546477/delete-all-foreign-keys-in-databasemysql - you can use system tables